# How to Grep for special characters in Linux

Tags: php, linux

I wanna grep this $_SESSION["sig"] in Linux, and find out all of files with this variable.  I used

```
grep -F "$_SESSION["sig"]" *
fgrep "\$_SESSION["sig"]" *
fgrep "\$_SESSION\[\"sig\"\]" *
```

but they are not working

How can I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `grep -F '$_SESSION["sig"]' *` command.

Comment: This will not work. `' '` does not recognize variables inside of it.

Comment: He doesn't need the variable, but the `'$_SESSION["sig"]'` in i.e. php file.

Comment: Again, this will not work. `' '` do NOT recognize variables inside of the single qoutes.

Comment: Kyan, glad to help you.
@OliverQueen, one more time, Kyan didn't want to recognize variables, but search for the string, not variable.